# SRS is reduced by increasing the bandwidth of the OC in high power fiber lasers generally. What happens if the bandwidth is increased too much?

Tags: optics, laser, fiber-optics, laser-cavity

Several articles suggest, in a MOPA configuration high power fiber laser, the SRS can be mitigated by increasing the bandwidth of the OC FBG. How to determine the optimized bandwidth of such FBG? Does the bandwidth of the HR FBG is also related? What is the relationship between the bandwidths of the FBGs and the amount of Raman output?

For example, we saw an SRS peak by using a 1.6nm OC. In order to reduce the SRS effect we inserted a 3nm bandwidth OC instead of the 1.6nm. Instead of a reduction in Raman, we observed multiple Raman peaks with the 3nm with a lot of back reflection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome @Chat0924. It is hoped that Physics Stack Exchange questions and answers will be useful to people with varying levels of expertise, so even though anyone likely able to answer your question will be familiar with the 5 acronyms you use in your question, it would be best to define each one or link them to a definition.